# Benchmarking C# code - results

Tags: cpu, benchmarking

I watch this YouTuber's mostly excellent videos on .NET features (let's call him Nick). He more often than not uses Benchmark.net to demonstrate the differences in performance of different approaches to programming problems.

The results this tool shows for statements or full methods that typically have quite a bit of logic in them are typically a couple of nanoseconds. Sometimes even less than a single nanosecond.

With my understanding of modern microprocessors I can't help but think this cannot be right.

Even if I take into account that the test will be executed multiple times (filling up the cache, pipelines, optimizing branch prediction results and all those goodies, likely rendering the results meaningless anyway), the numbers don't add up for me. A 3 GHz processor can, under optimal conditions, do a couple of operations per cycle, a cycle being 1/3 of a ns. That is still a far cry from any rudimentary C# statement which would take tens to hundreds of operations.

What is the deal with those numbers? What am I missing or how do they come up with those kind of results?

Comment: Would you mind to share some links to those videos?

Comment: @DocBrown Here's his latest one, first benchmark at 4:30. What is measured here should be pretty quick but the results still seem ridiculous. https://youtu.be/d76WWAD99Yo

Comment: Naively counted, *each core* of a 3ghz processor can do 3 things per ns. The computer I am typing at has 8 cores @ 3.8, so that makes it ~30 per ns already, not counting things the silicon does to execute more than one instruction per cycle

Comment: @Caleth Any single method is not going to be executed on more than one thread (unless you use Parallel.ForEach or some other specificly multi-threaded feature). That is not what this is about, this is all single-threaded.

Comment: The examples in the video relate to accessing auto-implemented properties of various C# objects, and invoking void methods which are empty. The CLR will inline these. For the sealed classes, the CLR can optimize the calls away entirely (and the benchmarking tool shows a warning). For the non-sealed classes, the CLR will have to do a tiny bit more bookkeeping, but I guess that loop unrolling within the benchmark harness reduces this to <1 cycle per invocation. But it's still benchmarking the cost of doing nothing, and the results are not particularly interpretable.

Comment: I think Amon is right, the video benchmarks about measuring empty functions aren't useful, they may be giving a distorted impression, because they contain too much of  the benchmark framework's overhead. If you want more meaningful results, make a benchmark of your own, but use methods dealiing with some real-world task.

Comment: _"The results this tool shows for statements or full methods that typically have quite a bit of logic in them are typically a couple of nanoseconds"_ can you provide an example other than the video linked above? I think we can all agree the numbers comparing the overheads of a virtual and non-virtual call are meaningless (the tool already tries to account for such overheads); other videos by the same guy seem to contain more sensible comparisons, with benchmarks that measure in the microseconds. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/how-it-works.html may be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t measure *one* execution of code in a meaningful way. But if something supposedly takes a nanosecond then you just do it a billion times and count the seconds, without any tools. If that’s too fast then you run it 10 billion times and count the seconds. If that is still too fast, the optimiser has optimised your code away :-)

Another possibility is automatic vectorising, and I once found a compiler that unrolled an empty loop eight times so instead of a billion iterations doing nothing it did 125 million iterations doing nothing. So my code said “one billion”, and it took 3/8ths of a billion cycles :-) (3 cycles for an empty loop).

Comment: There surely are some useful hints in this answer. Nethertheless it does not seeem to refer to any specifics of this question.